# Knitr: when knit RMarkdown to PDF, the code chunk is not returned as expected in PDF output

Tags: r, pdf, latex, knitr, r-markdown

I have a problem when knitting RMarkdown to PDF.
When I type the following, f1 is a list

````
```{r, echo=TRUE}
f1$fpevals
```
````

The output in PDF actually returned

```
\begin{CodeChunk}
\begin{CodeInput}
f1$fpevals
\end{CodeInput}
[1] 14659
\end{CodeChunk}
```

It outputs the latex command instead of the code and results only in PDF, why did that happen? Has anything to do with $ sign here? Anyone has any idea?

Comment: Is it only this code that doesn't knit to pdf, or everything?

Comment: Only this, up to this point, everything else is fine so I feel so strange. @alistaire

Answer (score 0):

Yes, `$` is the culprit. See a similar report [here](https://github.com/rstudio/rticles/issues/49). Try `f1[['fpevals']]` instead.